# The Elementary Evil vs You /Animatronics 2: Judgement Day/ We need a weakness!

Tags: science-based, robots

So, Anon has had enough of the DM abusing his poor creations (the chromatic dragons). Wanting a better fate for them, he wraps the DM in unbreakable chains, forged in the heart of a neutron star, and throws him into the Duna.

He has also prepared a special surprise for the adventurers, as "replacement dragons":

The first batch is the Faz Gang, a squad of four heavily armed animatronics, designed to hunt down adventurers.

### Characteristics:

- An animatronic is about 200 cm tall. Their main parts are the outer shell, chemically inert and designed to make them look more "kid-friendly" and the armored **endoskeleton**.
- The endoskeleton's outer layer is made of SAM2x5-630 bulk metallic glass, reinforced with graphene, it can withstand any firearm up to a .50 cal at point blank range.
- Locomotion is achieved through pneumatic artificial muscles, with multiple air bladders and compressors for extra redundancy.
- Animatronics have lithium-air batteries, with enough juice in them to be able to march for ~250 km before complete shutdown.
- Enhanced senses are obligatory, as well as radio trans-receivers and IR vision.
- Animatronics are fast, though Sir Isaac Newton puts a limit on their maneuverability at high speeds, see "*Mad Foxy misses nightguard and slides for 5 meters after punching through a brick wall"*
- Animatronics have optical cables for nerves so conduction velocity is about 299 792 458 m/s, or 'bout x1 of the speed of light.
- Equipment: [M82A1 Barret](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXprNBWoFCc&feature=youtu.be&t=894), [MK 19 automatic grenade launcher](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmTNOqFoAgg&feature=youtu.be&t=467), [M60 GPMG](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MSgKWDUK1U&feature=youtu.be&t=116), [M18A1 claymore](https://youtu.be/63yNAJSeVEE?t=351). For the duration of this question, we'll only focus on reloading, for everything else, assume infinite supplies of ammo.
- They also have a [hard-kill active protection system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trophy_(countermeasure)). It eats ATGMs like candy.
- The animatronics are usually together, so assume they always are.
- Their operating system is new and sturdy. And the bots would tear you to shred if you tried to plug anything in them.

Protocols (in priority):

1. Protec Anon's creations (well, sacrifice yourselves if, and only if, necessary)
2. No collateral damage, please! Otherwise, daddy will go to jail for a few thousand years.
3. Be stealthy, the fifth element is that of surprise.

You can see the problem, I need a **weakness**, a fatal flaw, attributes that can get the animatronics into an incrementally worse position through the domino effect, anything!

### What's the weakness' worth?

First criterion: **severity**

Second criterion: **areas of  severity**, in descending order:

1. Permanent, meaningful damage (What can cause it? Where?)
2. Something they are kinda bad at
3. Temporary hindrance

Of course, they all have to be viably exploitable for humans.

**What should the best weakness for animatronics be?**

**I'm not saying that you should write down multiple weakness, one is enough, and proper reasoning, for why they wouldn't be fixed, is vital.**

Comment: @Agrajag Anon is a t҉̢̩͖̮͖͓̺͘h̵̡̛̼͕̞͖͇̩͍̥e̛̖̱̬̦̕m̨̛̗̖̬̻̝̥͙͙̬̰̤̕, and knows pretty much what I know, so what don't I know?

Comment: The comment just vanished

Comment: What is their Operating System? Do they have GPS? WiFi?

Comment: They have GPS, but also common sense.

Comment: Lure them into a desert. The sand is coarse for robotic joints and it gets everywhere. (plus its irritating) ;)

Answer (score 2):

### Water

Robots don't like water, but real dragons are fine with it. I'm sure there's plenty around in your world, whether in oceans, streams, or just rain.

#### Solution 1: The Ocean

Make a boat and set sail for another place. I wish these poor robots the best of luck in following along, given that their density is somewhere between a rock and a pound of lead. If these creatures are likely to rampage and destroy creatures that have value, perhaps an [ark of biblical proportions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noah%27s_Ark) is more acceptable.

#### Solution 2: Streams

Your dragons are very powerful but very heavy. Fortunately, [with Ulmo on our side](https://middle-earth.xenite.org/are-the-nazgul-really-afraid-of-water/), we can cross any stream deeper than 2 meters and they'll be forced to go the long way around. Find a river that hasn't been crossed yet and float/wade across it, and you've saved yourself a whole lot of trouble.

#### Solution 3: Rain

I'll let Randall take this one:

[image: An XKCD comic about robots not liking rain]

Comment: What makes you think they don't follow you with a water bike? Foxy can pedal really fast.

Answer (score 2):

**Molotovs**

Your robots have electrical equipment and motors/muscles inside them. These need to be cooled down so your robot cannot be thermally insulated from the outside world. A moltov will cause this internal temperature to shoot up into the 100s causing internal electrical failure, muscles and signals to misfire and parts to become misaligned due to thermal expansion. It will likely also cause the battery to explode/fail as it overheats.

It doesn't even matter if you glue it together and make it waterproof. You need some way to vent the heat, so there is some medium there for heat transfer which a Molotov will be able to get to. (Just look at any computer for the vents they use, or feel your phone when your using a fast charger).

**Other solutions**

Water bombs/Acid. Your robots need to move. Moving parts have gaps in them. Liquids are great for getting into these gaps, getting into the internal components and messing them up.

Answer (score 0):

**The weakness of these animatronics is that they can only perceive their immediate surroundings.**

If one of these things is within visual range of you then you are pretty much toast.  But if you steer clear, how will it find you?  They are not psychic.  They don't have spotter planes or satellite uploads.  They don't have scouts.   I doubt they can smell.  You keep radio silence.  The world is big and adventurers are small.  The robots could split up and search but that strategy poses hazards to lone animatronics.

It is much like fighting the armed forces of a first world country.  Or fighting Mongo in the movie Blazing Saddles.  Or both.  You do not want to engage such enemies on their terms.  Keep them looking.  Decoys and fakes welcome.  Crystal balls or Far Seeing spells will be helpful.  Ideally lure these hunter / killer bots into circumstances where they will encounter (and have to fight) enemies which are their equal, or cope with hazardous natural phenomena (like landslides / tar pits).  Best of all is if after they split up and search, you can trick them into fighting each other.

---

**Radio mimic.**

Presumably these animatronics are in radio communication with each other.  If they can hear each other then you can hear them.  Depending on their sophistication, radio commmuncations might or might not be encrypted.  If you can break the encryption you can pretend to be one of them.  If you can't break the encryption you can flood their channels with noise, prohibiting communication between animatronics.  If these animatronics rely on radio to communicate with one another and radio becomes unusable, their ability to cooperate (and avoid shooting each other) is much impaired.

Answer (score 0):

**EMP**

These animatronics were not mentioned to have any sort of faraday netting on them, so a powerful EMP blast (most probably from a [Nuclear Artillery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_artillery) rocket) would knock them out or disrupt their radios at the very least. Then they're either dead or will start fighting themselves.

But why won't they have the netting?

They identify each other by radio, which means that even if there was netting there would have to be a gap to transmit radio signals. A small atomic explosion would make mincemeat out of even the smallest gap in the shield and knock out at least the radio.